# Ajuda para escrever código

Tags: c

Como devo fazer para utilizar o Dev-c++ com este código.
Como traduzi-lo para C?

Comecei há pouco tempo com programação, estou meio enrolado para entender algumas coisas.

```
Programa CalculoMedia 
Var 
 N1, N2, MEDIA: Real 
Início 
Leia N1 
Leia N2 
MEDIA ← (N1+N2)/2 
Se MEDIA >=6 Então 
 Escreva “Aluno aprovado com média: ”, MEDIA 
 Senão 
 Escreva “Aluno reprovado com média: ”, MEDIA 
Fim Se 
Fim.
```

Comment: Mas este problema só necessita dos comandos básicos da linguagem C. 15 minutos de estudo e você estará apto a solucionar seu dever de casa.

Comment: Matheus, retornei a pergunta ao seu estado original mais compreensível, para que a resposta aceita não fique fora de contexto. Se você tem **novas** dúvidas, mesmo que sejam à respeito do mesmo programa, crie uma nova pergunta, explicando seu problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para transcrever esse programa para linguagem c, primeiro é necessario um metodo `main` que é equivalente a instruçao `programa <nome>`

as instruções `leia` e `escreva` devem ser substiuidas por [printf](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~joaoreis/Site%20de%20tutoriais/c_int/printf.htm) e [scanf](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2012/12/A-funcao-scanf-recebendo-numeros-do-usuario.html), `se` por `if` e fimse por `{`

segue um exemplo de como deve a sintaxe:

```
#include <stdio.h> // declara printf e scanf, usados abaixo

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {// equivalente ao programa
    int numero; //equivalente ao var
    printf("digite um numero: "); // serve para imprimir caracteres na tela
    scanf("%d", &numero); // leitura de um valor

    if(numero > 10){ // se
        printf("numero maior que 10");
    }else{// se não
        printf("numero menor que 10");
    }// fimse
    return 0;
}// fim do programa
```

Comment: Faltou o `return 0;`

Comment: estou tentando mais esta dando um erro:[Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'scanf' [enabled by default]

Comment: @matheusferreira adicione o `#include <stdio.h>` no topo.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, obrigado por acertar o `#include`.

Answer (score -1):

O `IF` está errado faltou as chaves tente assim:

```
if(MEDIA >=6){
    printf ("Alunos aprovados com media: ", MEDIA);
}
    else{
    printf ("Alunos reprovados com media: ", MEDIA);
}
```